# How do I use hook_theme() in a module?

Tags: hooks, theming

I need help in using hook_theme in my custom module. Any good examples is much appreciated. I have created a CCK input form and I want to theme the input form using hook_theme. The content type is created using `hook_install()`.

I have used `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` to alter the theme of the input form. Following is the code for that.

```
 function footer_menu_form_footer_menu_node_form_alter(&$form,&$form_state,$form_id) {
   theme('footer_menu_node_form', array('form' => $form));
 }

 function footer_menu_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
   return array('footer_menu_node_form' => array(
     'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
     'template' => 'footer-menu-node-form',
     'render element'=> 'form',
   ));
 }
```

I have also created a footer-menu-node-form.tpl.php file inside the module, and the following is the code in the template file.

```
 <div id="title"> <?php print drupal_render($form['title']); ?>
 <div id="tree">
 <h2>Menu Tree</h2>
  </div>
 <?php print drupal_render($form['title']); ?>
 // this one is for rendering all the remaining items, like hiddens:
<?php print drupal_render($form); ?>
```

When I load the footer menu content type. The content within the `<h2>` tag is alone printed and then I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 40961 bytes)

Can anyone tell me what I doing wrong, or could anyone suggest me an efficient way to use `hook_theme()` in modules?

Comment: You should also show the code for `footer_menu_node_form()`, or it is not possible to answer this question without giving guesses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to assign a theme function to a form using `hook_form_alter()` is like this:

```
function footer_menu_form_footer_menu_node_form_alter(&$form,&$form_state,$form_id){
  $form['#theme'] = 'pz_footer_menu_node_form';
}
```

I can't tell if you're using Drupal 6 or 7; you're using the `arguments` property in your theme declaration which is only valid in Drupal 6, and also the `render element` property which is only valid in Drupal 7.

Judging by the out of memory error I'm guessing Drupal 7. As you call `drupal_render()` on the the `$form` object in your template file, it runs that variable back through the same theme function, and you end up with an infinite loop.

Try changing the last line in your template file to this:

```
<?php print drupal_render_children($form); ?>
```

That should stop the error from happening.

Comment: I am using Drupal 7. I am new to drupal 7 and its really confusing. and no proper online resources as well.

Comment: @DrupalDeveloper I just realised you're probably using D7; I've updated the answer, it should solve the problem

Comment: There are loads of good resources out there for Drupal 7, it's just knowing where to find them really. Personally I'd recommend reading [Pro Drupal 7 Development](http://www.drupalbook.com/), it's a great book. Also check out the [Examples module](http://drupal.org/project/examples), it has tons of Drupal API examples.

Comment: thank you very much for your help and support. You have been clarifying most of my questions. I am indebt to you.

Comment: should I pass the arugment in hook_theme for drupal 7

Comment: `arguments` was actually renamed to `variables` in Drupal 7 so normally you'd use that; but as you're using `render element` on a form there's no need to pass `variables` as well. You can take out `arguments` altogether and everything should still work fine :)

Comment: can you please tell me what are the arguments that could be passed to hook_theme function.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3219/discussion-between-drupal-developer-and-clive)

Answer (score 1):

In your theme function definition, you use the "arguments" index, but you should use the "variables" index; then, as reported in [hook_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7), "variables" and "render element" exclude each other: If you are using one, you should not use the other.

> Each information array must contain **either a 'variables' element or a 'render element' element, but not both**. Use 'render element' if you are theming a single element or element tree composed of elements, such as a form array, a page array, or a single checkbox element. Use 'variables' if your theme implementation is intended to be called directly through theme() and has multiple arguments for the data and style

Using [drupal_render()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render/7) could cause an infinite loop, but only if `$form`, or one of its sub-elements uses the `#theme` (or `#theme_wrappers`) property, and that property points to a theme function using the same template file that you are showing in your question.

`drupal_render()` calls `theme()`, but only in two cases.

```
  if (isset($elements['#theme'])) {
    $elements['#children'] = theme($elements['#theme'], $elements);
  }
```

```
  if (isset($elements['#theme_wrappers'])) {
    foreach ($elements['#theme_wrappers'] as $theme_wrapper) {
      $elements['#children'] = theme($theme_wrapper, $elements);
    }
  }
```

If `$elements['#theme_wrappers']` and `$elements['#theme_wrappers']` (where `$elements` is the argument passed to `drupal_render()`) are not defined, `drupal_render()` doesn't call `theme()`.

Comment: This is what i ve been looking for.I will try this method and let you know.